# Is there a way to change color of specific DT lines when using bslib and bootstrap5?

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-5, dt, bslib

I'm building an app using R shiny, bslib and DT.

With former version of bootstrap, it was simple to change the styling of the DT (including clolor of some line) using *formatStyle* function.
But, for the new app, we use bslib and bootstrap 5 and the function seems broken, even if a user on github says it should be resolved (https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1102).
After some tests with different versions of DT and bslib (release and dev), I was still not able to make it work.

Is there another way to dynamically change the color of some composents of a DT with bslib and bootstrap 5?

```
library(bslib)
library(DT)

ui <- function(id) {
 card(
   DT::dataTableOutpu("repeatsTable")
}

server <- function(id) ({      
  output$repeatsTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
  repeatsDT <- DT::datatable(repeatsData(),
        extensions = c("Buttons", "ColReorder"),
        selection = "single",
        options = list(
          dom = "Bfrtip",
          buttons = list(I("colvis")),
          scrollX = TRUE,
          colReorder = TRUE
        )
      ) %>%
        formatStyle("isPathogenic", target = "row", color = styleEqual(c(0, 1, 2), c("black", "orange", "red")))
    })
})
```

edit: adding a dummy code of work (from link upper) that can run on itself

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(bslib)

ui <- bslib::page_sidebar(
  DT::DTOutput("tab1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDT({
    mtcars %>% 
      head() %>% 
      # this line works
      #DT::datatable(style = "default") %>% 
      DT::datatable() %>% 
      DT::formatStyle(
        columns = "mpg", 
        target = "row", 
        color = DT::styleEqual(c(21), "white"),
        backgroundColor = DT::styleEqual(c(21), "#4d4d4d"),
      )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the cells also have some CSS properties and they have priority over the CSS properties of the rows. A workaround is to unset the CSS properties of the cells:

```r
  output$tab1 <- DT::renderDT({
    mtcars %>% 
      head() %>% 
      DT::datatable() %>% 
      DT::formatStyle(
        columns = 1:ncol(mtcars), 
        target = "cell", 
        color = JS("\"unset\""),
        backgroundColor = JS("\"unset\"")
      ) %>%
      DT::formatStyle(
        columns = "mpg", 
        target = "row", 
        color = DT::styleEqual(c(21), "white"),
        backgroundColor = DT::styleEqual(c(21), "orange")
      )
  })
```

Comment: Thant you, the workaround works perfectly!